# How to filter by selected date from one table and filtering a different table

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax

I am trying to select date from **ProjectParameterStartDate[ProjectStartDate]**.

Use the selected date to filter the column **PojectTimeBase[Duration]** so that is shows data from the selected date which is in the past to todays date.

```
filterDate =
VAR selectedDate =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( ProjectParameterStartDate[ProjectStarted] )
RETURN
    FILTER (
        ProjectTimeBase,
        ProjectTimeBase[Project - Copy.ProjectStarted] <= selectedDate
    )
```

And I get the error below;

> ERROR: The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns
>   cannot be converted to a scalar value.

Comment: You are getting the error because FILTER function returns a table. It's unclear from the provided information what you are trying to do though. What's the purpose of this measure?

Comment: @RADO I am trying to filter by date a column of data from a date in a different table in a column.

Comment: can you post a shot of your data model please?